# Best way to synchronize Android db local and MySQL

Tags: android, xml, web-services, synchronization

I have an Android application that should consume XML from a web server. When the data to be synchronized is small, the synchronization that i have done works perfectly, but when the data is larger the application fails and does not finishes the synchronization. When I say larger i'm saying 19 MB of XML to consume and insert it in Android local database. What can I do to solve this?
Sorry for my English.

Here some code:

```
String resposta = Util.executePost(context,"RelacionamentoCelularPontoDeVendaProduto/ListarRelacionamentos", pairs);
if(resposta.contains("<lista>")) {
        resposta = resposta.substring(resposta.indexOf("<lista>")+7, resposta.indexOf("</lista>"));
        String[] dados = resposta.split("<item xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xsi:type=\"relacionamentoCelularPontoDeVendaProdutoVO\">");
        String pontoStr, produtoStr;
        ProdutoVO produto;
        for (String dado : dados) {
            if(dado.contains("<pontoDeVenda>") && dado.contains("</pontoDeVenda>") && dado.contains("<produto>") && dado.contains("</produto>")){
                item = new RelacionamentoPontoDeVendaProdutoVO();
                pontoStr = dado.substring(dado.indexOf("<pontoDeVenda>") + "<pontoDeVenda>".length() , dado.indexOf("</pontoDeVenda>"));
                item.setPontoDeVenda(new PontoDeVendaVO(Integer.parseInt(pontoStr.substring(pontoStr.indexOf("<id>") + "<id>".length() , pontoStr.indexOf("</id>")))));

                lista.add(item);
            }
        }
    }
    return lista;
```

this list called lista in the first syncronization has 45000 registers to be inserted in Android local database. ´

Comment: are you using asynctasks?

Comment: Yes, i'm using assyncTask.

Comment: then this is not suppose to happen..can you provide some code?

Comment: @JohanV i post some code..

Comment: ok...I would in this case use Volley for retrieving data ...do you know about Volley?

Comment: I did some research and am convinced using volley to handle large amount of data from the server is the right way to go...if you need some help with volley I will be more than happy help you out since I have some projects using it.

Comment: Thanks @JohanV, i dont know about Volley, but i will research, and see what can i do.

Comment: @JohanV man, i read about Volley, but how it will helps me in my case ?

Comment: I was thinking about volley since can handle drop outs and can easily resume maybe it will help with your crashing...volley is by far a better solution than the standard HTTP manager in android....volley is very easy to implement so basically of you pass an hour testing you will know if it helps with your case....another solution for you can be the Download Manager which is the preferred solution by Google for downloading large amount of data.

Comment: I used, module deflate of apache, and i change my return from webserver to json, is working now, but i have another problem.. I nedd insert in Android local database, 45000 register in a table.. whats the best way to do this ?